# creating a dropdown list in a form_for helper referring to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im new to ruby on rails, im trying to create a dropdown list in a form_for helper referring to another model (users). basically, im trying to select from list of users so that their email will be copied to the receiver field.

here's what i have so far, i can only manually type in the email address:

```
<%= form_for :femail, url: {action: "create"} do |form| %>
<p>
 <%= form.label :from %><br>
 <%= form.text_field :from %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.label :to %><br>
  <%= form.text_area :to %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.label :subject %><br>
<%= form.text_field :subject %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.label :body %><br>
  <%= form.text_area :body %>
</p>
<p>
 <%= form.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to have your set of users coming from somewhere (maybe your controller?), I'm going to call it `@users`. Then you can do something like:

```
<p>
  <%= form.label :to %><br>
  <%= form.select(:to, options_for_select(@user.map { |u| [u.name, u.email]}) ) %>
</p>
```

That will show you a set of options that display the user.name, but will actually submit the value user.email. The `select` tag has some pretty useful options (e.g. setting default values, not accepting blank entries, etc).

More info: [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models) of the Rails guides and the [FormOptionsHelper docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select).